Where can I obtain row/path data for the SPOT satellites?
I've been asked to get hold of a shapefile (or any other spatial format) that shows the path and rows of a SPOT 6/7 satellite, specifically covering the country Qatar.  I just need the rectangle, not the actual image.
USGS provides their Landsat path/rows as shapefiles or KML on this page, so I'm looking for an equivalent dataset for the SPOT satellite.
I've also checked out earthexplorer but the SPOT data they offer does not cover Qatar.
Does anyone know where I could obtain such a dataset, as my wanderings of the internet have failed to turn up anything?
